# Why is my code showing only raw HTML although it's in PHP tags

Tags: php, html, variables

This is a bit of a noob question (sorry) however I am creating a deck builder and shuffler from an IBM tutorial in PHP. It seems however that I may have formatted the code wrongly as it is not reading the code, but rather displaying raw HTML. Below I have put the actual code I have written and then below that what is being displayed in my browser.

```
    <?php 
    $suits = array(
      "Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"
      );
    $faces = array(
       "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight","Nine", "Ten",
       "Eleven","Joker","Queen", "King", "Ace");

    $deck = array();
    foreach ($suits as $suit){
        foreach($faces as $face){
           $desk[] = array("face" =>$face, "suit"=>$suit);
        }
    }

    shuffle($desk);
    $card = array_shift($desk);
    echo $card['face'] . 'of ' . $card['suit'];

    ?>
```

This is what I get in my browser:

```
$face, "suit"=>$suit); } } shuffle($desk); $card = array_shift($desk); echo $card['face'] . ' of ' . $card['suit']; ?>
```

Comment: page not being parsed as php, is the file *.php? you have a web server with php installed ...

Comment: Is your code running on a server that has PHP installed and running?

Comment: Wouldn't you guys think that its returning an array, because its not returning the same exact code as he showed? I'd expect it to start with `$suits = array(
      "Spades","Hearts","Clubs","Diamonds"
      );` Not `$face, "suit"=>$suit); } } `

Comment: @Idris - http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FtWz3/

Comment: browser usually just ignores the start thinking its borked (technical term) html

Comment: It seems your file is NOT being processed by PHP. IS PHP enabled in your web server?

Comment: Is your code running on a server that has PHP installed and running? It seems your file is NOT being processed by PHP. Is PHP enabled in your web server? **;p**

Comment: @Dagon I was hoping someone would notice ;p

Comment: i wish people that asked questions at least had the decency to check back in a reasonable time frame

Comment: @Dagon It would help if you quit being a pretentious snob, some of us have not been doing this as as long as you. Thanks to everyone else for helping, it seems like that is exactly what I am missing. Very rookie error.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working it print  Output is :Kingof Spades,Threeof Hearts,Sevenof Diamonds etc output is different on each refresh of page.
I just copied above code in file and stored as data.php and executed it in browser and I got an output properly. 
So that you have to check following points first :
Please, check is there PHP installed or not ? 
And it's extension should be .php